# cheerio / jquery selectors: how to get text in tag a?

Tags: cheerio

I am trying to access links on a website. The website looks like the first code sample and the links are in different div-containers:

```
<div id="list">
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="item-class1">
      <a href="http://www.example.com/1">example1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="item-class2">
      <a href="http://www.example.com/2">example2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did tried to extract the links with this code:

```
var list = [];
$('div[id="list"]').find('a').each(function (index, element) {
  list.push($(element).attr('href'));
});
```

But the outputs look like this:

```
0: "http://www.example.com/1"
1: "http://www.example.com/2"
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
0: example1
1: example2
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$(element).attr('href')` ==> get href property : the link

`$(element).text()`    ==> get text

just change like this :

```
var list = [];
    $('div[id="list"]').find('a').each(function (index, element) {
      list.push($(element).text());
    });
```