# How to find the corresponding div closing tag?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a html code like following

```
<div class="body">
 <h1>ddd</h1>
 <p>dadfsaf</p>
 <div id="name">
  <div class="des">psd</div>
  <div>www</div>
 </div>
 <div>ppp</div>
</div>
```

I would like to get the content inside a div that starts with `<div id="name">` and ends with its corresponding closing tag. Here the content is

```
<div class="des">psd</div>
<div>www</div>
```

I tried `<div id="name">.*</div>`, but it doesn't work. Please help, thank you.

Append, I wrote this code in node.js.

Comment: Do you want the HTML of `#name` or the elements? `document.querySelector('#name').innerHTML` will get you the HTML; `document.querySelector('#name').children` will get you the elements. Are you doing this in node, or in the front-end?

Comment: use a library to parse HTML, not regex see: [cheerio / jquery selectors: how to get text in tag a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379384/cheerio-jquery-selectors-how-to-get-text-in-tag-a)

Comment: @Andy Thank you, but I find a way in Node.js

Comment: [How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js)

Comment: the only way is to use a library, otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $("#name").html()
console.log(name)
```

Comment: you can do in javascript

`element = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
console.log(element)`